# Unable to scroll rows after binding Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism-4

Here is my code in XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="OpportunitySearchResultLV" ItemsSource="{Binding OpportunityCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" AlternationCount="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOpportunitySearchedItem}" Margin="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" >
                <ListView.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding SelectOpportunitySearchDetailsCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick"></MouseBinding>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SelectOpportunitySearchDetailsCommand}" Key="Up"></KeyBinding>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SelectOpportunitySearchDetailsCommand}" Key="Down"></KeyBinding>
                    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding OpportunitySearchDetailsLeaveCommand}" Key="Tab"></KeyBinding>
                </ListView.InputBindings>               
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource NOGridViewHeader}" >
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Viewbox>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OpportunityTitle}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Viewbox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <msia:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <msia:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                    <msia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectOpportunitySearchDetailsCommand}" />
                                </msia:EventTrigger>
                            </msia:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </GridViewColumn>                        
                    </GridView>                    
                </ListView.View>                
            </ListView>
```

now as you can see I am binding (MouseBinding and KeyBinding) but as I am using upkey and downkey I am unable to traverse through the rows in listview.It is stuck to only one row only. Can anyone advise me why this is happening ? My binding is working perfectly and as per expected result also.Moreover I would like to add that I have not found any way to bind GridViewColumn so I am binding (MouseBinding and KeyBinding) to Listview . Is it proper way or there is a better way to bind? Thanking you .Payel Mukherjee Bangalore India